# Prevent PDF storing invisible map data

Tags: r, dictionary, pdf, ggplot2, spatial

When saving maps as PDF in R, the pdf still stores map data (polygons, polylines) that are in the object being plotted but outside the visible area of the map. Is there any way to prevent that?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)


continent <- map_data('world') %>%
  filter(region %in% c("Canada", "USA")) %>% fortify()

pdf(file = ".../Results/My Plot.pdf", width=8, height=4)
# pdf() or ggsave() give the same results

ggplot()+ 
  geom_polygon(data = continent, aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group),
               fill="lightgray", colour = NA) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-82, -57), ylim = c(28, 43), expand = FALSE)

dev.off()
```

The map as seen in the pdf

[image: PDF map]

The map in Inkscape, with the main plot "ungrouped" (as in https://inkscape-manuals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/grouping.html - `ungrouping` the main part of the plot 2 or 3 times).
[image: Inkscape map]

Comment: Just a tip: Try to make sure your example is reproducible. As it is now there are (at least) multiple library calls missing. Also a more generic save path would probably be better..

Comment: What do you mean by "ungrouped"?

Comment: @captcoma See my comment to your answer: Ungrouping https://inkscape-manuals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/grouping.html

Comment: This is a general thing in R, not just something that happens maps or ggplot2. Same thing happens with something like a simple `plot(c(2,6,8,3,6,4,9,2,4)~c(-3:5), type="l", xlim=c(0,3))`.

Comment: Also: using `cairo_pdf()` instead of the regular `pdf()` won't change this, nor will using `svg()`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I see that my answer did not solve this.

Comment: @Where'smytowel is there a generic solution to this problem?

Comment: @captcoma I'm not aware of any, but I haven't spend much time looking for one ...

Comment: This has some information about how clipping works in R: [Improved Clipping in the R Graphics Engine](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Reports/GraphicsEngine/r-clipping/r-clipping.html)

Comment: Thanks @Where'smytowel: not sure how these improvements trickle down to basic users but hopefully graphic packages will incorporate them in future updates.

Comment: Unfortunatly, that kind of seems to suggest that there may be no clean solution to this problem. And in most cases, it really is not a problem anyway. But I've run into issues with big maps in the past too, where the additional hidden data meant that the figure was really difficult to handle in something like Inkscape. I wonder if it would make sense to turn this question into a more general one (i.e. plotting to PDF in general, not only maps). That could maybe attract some more eyes from people who will skip this question because they don't work with maps ...

Comment: A way around it is to clip any spatialpolygons to the extent being plotted but it can become very cumbersome and can take up unnecessary computing time very quickly. Good point about opening a more general question.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-November/261663.html

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to remove the unwanted data point from `continent`.

A quick (and somewhat dirty) workaround would be to save the plot as a `png` and convert it to a `PDF`:

```r
#library
library(tidyverse)
library(maps)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(png)

# generate data
continent <- map_data('world') %>%
  filter(region %in% c("Canada", "USA")) %>% fortify()

#make plot
plot <- ggplot()+ 
  geom_polygon(data = continent, aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group),
               fill="lightgray", colour = NA) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-82, -57), ylim = c(28, 43), expand = TRUE, clip="on")

# plot plot
plot
```

[image]

```r
#save plot
ggsave("test.png",dpi=500)
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image


# load png and make a raster
rasterGrob(readPNG("test.png", native = FALSE),
           interpolate = FALSE) -> go

# print PDF
go1 <- list(go)
pdf("test.pdf")
do.call(grid.arrange, c(go1, ncol = 1))
dev.off()
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

PDF in Inkscape after using "ungroup" multiple times (does not bring back the data outside the plot):
[image]

Comment: Hi, although that works visually, it defeats the purpose of saving vector objects to a PDF, since PNG saves raster objects. I.e. the PNG map in your example cannot be "ungrouped" because it's a raster, and hence it cannot be modified by vector-based software either.