# How to avoid duplicated graphical objects in ggplots such as sometimes seen in PDF output?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pdf

In the past, I noticed that ggplot (and base graphics) plot "invisible" data when creating PDF files ([Prevent PDF storing invisible map data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69850920/prevent-pdf-storing-invisible-map-data)).

I just noticed that, when creating PDF files, ggplot also plots unnecessary duplicates of graphic elements. The number of duplicates corresponds with the number of observations in the dataframe being plotted.

For example, in the example below, the `mpg` dataset has 234 observations.

```
library(ggplot2)
nrow(mpg)
> 234
```

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))
p + geom_boxplot()+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 5, y = 40, xend = 6, yend = 40))+
  geom_text(label = "***", x = 5.5, y = 41, size = 6)
ggsave("mtcars.pdf")
```

In the created PDF, 234 copies of "***" are superimposed on top of each other. This is the normal behavior of `geom_text`, as the help file states: `geom_text() and geom_label() add labels for each row in the data`. 
**However**, 234 duplicates of the `geom_segment` are are also created, although the help file does not suggest this is a normal behavior. 
This is not really visible in the PDF (except for the *** and segment looking as if they were in bold font/thicker) but it creates unnecessary objects that can increase the PDF size for no reason, especially when dealing with large amount of outliers.

I only checked `geom_segment`: the same may be true with other elements.

Has anyone any clues to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Well, when you use `geom_text` you get a label for each row of your dataset. if you want only one label use `annotate`.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question about `geom_text`. It's still unclear why `geom_segment` has the same behavior.

Comment: Well, the same holds for geom_segment. Use annotate if just want one sgement.

Comment: I'll look into `annotate`.
Although I can understand that this is the expected behavior for `geom_text` (given that it's explained in the help file), this behavior is not in the `geom_segment` help file, so I'm not sure why (and what for) it's happening.

Comment: You have set `data = mpg` globally, so all `geom_*` layers will plot "using" that data -- though in this case you have specified that for each observation in the data the mapping should come not from columns in that data but from constants you have provided. When the help for `geom_segment` says that the `data` parameter is "the data to be displayed in this layer", that's what it means.

Comment: Ok. If I may humbly suggest to whoever is maintaining the `ggplot2`'s helpfiles, it is not clear that "the data to be displayed in this layer" means the global data. A sentence like the one in the `geom_text` helpfile ("`geom_text()` and `geom_label()` add labels for each row in the data") would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem described affects all output formats, not just PDF. Of course, it is more visible when the output is in a vector graphics format like PDF than for bitmaps. In extreme cases it will slowdown rendering of plots to any graphical device. The root of the problem is in a misundertanding of how the *layered grammar ot graphics* works as implemented in recent versions of 'ggplot2' and what I consider a surprising behaviour of aesthetic mappings.

I show three solutions to the problem behind this question and explain what is behing it. The first solution, agrees with the first suggestions provided in the comments and the second is an alternative, which although requiring more verbose code is applicable to additional cases. The third one is copied from the comment by @stefan.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mpg, mapping = aes(class, hwy)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  annotate(geom = "segment", x = 5, y = 40, xend = 6, yend = 40)+
  annotate(geom = "text", label = "***", x = 5.5, y = 41, size = 6)
```

[image]

```r
ggsave("mtcars.pdf")
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

With `annotate()` multiple annotations can be added by passing vectors of length > 1 using the approach above. However, `annotate()` does not "know" about facets, so in the case of plots with facets, the only way of having different annotations in each panel is to use the geoms directly, but passing a different data frame as data to them than the one used for other geoms. This approach, shown below, is overkill in this case with a single plot panel and a single annotation, but is more general and works with facets. I also find the code easier to understand.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy)) + 
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_segment(data = data.frame(x = 5, y = 40, xend = 6, yend = 40),
               mapping = aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend))+
  geom_text(data = data.frame(label = "***", x = 5.5, y = 41),
            mapping = aes(x, y, label = label), size = 6)
```

[image]

```r
ggsave("mtcars3.pdf")
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

A third possibility is to pass constant values as arguments to `aes()` when setting the mapping, as described by @stefan and @Jon Spring in their comments, with no default data at whole-plot level.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_boxplot(data = mpg, aes(class, hwy)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 5, y = 40, xend = 6, yend = 40)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = "***", x = 5.5, y = 41), size = 6)
```

[image]

```r
ggsave("mtcars2.pdf")
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

These three approaches are equivalent in that they prevent `geom_segment()` and `geom_text()` from seeing `mpg` as their data input. In the first case, because `annotate()` ensures this by design, in the second case because we override with a local data argument the whole-plot default data, and in the third example, avoiding the creation of a default by not passing an argument for data within the call to `ggplot()`.

This third approach became usable only a few years back in the history of 'ggplot2'. As formerly using `aes()` to map constant values was disallowed or interprepet differently. Mapping contant values in `aes()` remains, I think, confusing to users in that mapping aesthetics to constants does not override the whole-plot default for data even when these data are no longer mapped to any aesthetic in a geom, resulting in the surprising behaviour described in this question.

This surprising, at least to me, behaviour can be more clearly demonstrated with an additional, contrieved, example, based on calling `data.frame()` with default arguments to construct an "empty" data frame to pass as argument to override the whole-plot data. No error is caused by the empty dataframes, and a plot is generated correctly as no easthetic mapping is missing. That multiple copies of the graphical objects are generated based on the number of rows in data that are not mapped to aesthetics is "surprising" behaviour. It seems that this behaviour originated from changes to the behaviour of `aes()` during the development of 'ggplot2'.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mpg, aes(class, hwy)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_segment(data = data.frame(), aes(x = 5, y = 40, xend = 6, yend = 40)) + 
  geom_text(data = data.frame(), aes(label = "***", x = 5.5, y = 41), size = 6)
```

[image]

```r
ggsave("mtcars2.pdf")
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

NOTE: There are three commonly used geometries that are unusual in that they behave as annotations or not depending on the presence of a mapping `geom_hline()`, `geom_vline()` and `geom_abline()`.

Comment: You may add `ggplot() + geom_boxplot(data = mpg, aes(class, hwy)) + geom_segment(aes(x = 5, y = 40, xend = 6, yend = 40)) + geom_text(aes(label = "***", x = 5.5, y = 41), size = 6)` as a third option as suggested in the comment by Jon Spring.

Comment: I have raised [issue #5253](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5253) at GitHub in the repository for 'ggplot2'. I think this behaviour could be considered a minor bug, but whether it will be fixed or not, and when, depends on what the 'ggplot2' maintainers decide.

Comment: Thanks Pedro for taking the time to answer so clearly. As you have well understood, `Mapping contant values in aes() remains [...] confusing to users`. Many users (me included) use ggplot here and there at discrete times in their projects and do not dive into the depths of such (apparently peculiar) behaviors (for lack of time, interest, or sills, among others). In particular, what confused me is thinking that a `geom_segment` would need to be applied to a whole global dataset, when the specific parameters of the segment are defined by the user.